# Default browser is automatically reset to Chrome

Tags: chrome-for-android, firefox-for-android

Firefox is my default browser since forever, until as of a sudden it stopped to be, and Chrome is set as default. I can set it back to Firefox but it eventually lasts only for some time.

[image]

Suddenly when I open a url I will open again in Chrome. This is a very annoying behavior, and I don't know how to fix it. I want Firefox as my default browser.

- Phone Model: Galaxy S10+
- Android Version: 12
- OneUI: 4.1

Comment: I have never had that issue.  Mind you I use Brave as the default browser for the last 3 years, I use to use Firefox.  Maybe it's because it's Firefox Beta.  I am guessing that its signature changes on every build.

Comment: well it even changes the same day i.e. no updates of FF take place

Comment: @Rohit you might be right at all. I switched to FF non-beta and the issue seems gone. If you answer my question I happily vote for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because it's Firefox Beta. I am guessing that its signature changes on every build.

Recommended fix: **install Firefox (non-beta)**